# Is it possible to deploy an application with WildFly as a bundle?

Tags: java, wildfly, java-ee-7, glassfish-embedded

Is it possible to deploy an application with WildFly as a bundle?

I am able to do this with embedded Glassfish.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to embed JBoss/Wildfly with your app, you should review [Wildfly Swarm](http://wildfly-swarm.io/). That's a way to generate an application that contains the server embedded. It's very similar to Spring Boot, but you can use Java EE APIs.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [JBoss documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/JBOSGI/Getting+Started) there has been something for OSGi, rather than there is... 
To me it looks like this has died before wildfly was released.